# mysql Select Query 2 where options

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write a query to select products from a database for a search page, at the moment the query is really simple

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 ORDER BY id DESC
```

This query brings back products fine starting from the newest, we will be going into sale soon so I need to change the query to order by the newest product on sale descending, then go onto display the remaining products that aren't on descending. If a product is on sale rrp is not equal to 0. Is there a way where I can do this without having to run two separate queries?

Is was thinking something like

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 ORDER BY (rrp != 0) DESC, id DESC
```

but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*but that doesn't work*"?  How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE stock > 0 
ORDER BY 
Case when rrp != 0 then 0 else 1 end,
id DESC
```

Comment: I can't use rrp != 0 as I still need to show products not in sale after the ones in sale have been displayed

Answer (score 2):

You can ORDER by multiple columns

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 ORDER BY rrp DESC, id DESC
```

or with 2 wheres

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 AND rrp != 0 ORDER id DESC
```

Comment: I thought of that but the first orders by the most expensive first (not the newest product in sale) and the second doesn't bring back products not in sale after the ones in sale

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock > 0 and rrp != 0 ORDER BY rrp DESC, id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your RRP works like a boolean here to determine if a product is on sale or not.

Please check on the following reference [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a88/2)

```
select * from sale
where stock>0
and rrp <>0
order by stock desc, id

ID  STOCK   RRP
3   490     1
4   200     1
1   120     1
```

It seems like you may have other intentions than the simplest requirement you mentioned here..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       SELECT * 
              FROM products 
       WHERE stock > 0 

       CASE  WHEN rrp != 0 THEN (ORDER BY rrp DESC) 
       CASE  WHEN rrp= 0   THEN (ORDER BY id DESC)
```